# Sites Internal link does not work after set up SSL (https)

Tags: laravel, ssl, centos

I have a production site developed using Laravel. After configure SSL only main domain work with https. No other route working. it says "404" not found. But the same link work with Http.

Server Detail:
PHP 7.1.29
Apache 2.4.6
OS: Centos 7
Laravel 5.4.*

.htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php70___lsphp .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

vhost.conf (sitename replaced by example)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
       Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com/error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com/access.log combined
<Directory "/var/www/html/example.com/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

#ssl configure
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
#SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/example/example.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/example/example.key"
SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/example/example.ca-bundle"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can you check your mod_rewrite is enabled ?

Comment: Yeah its enabled